# Compiling CUDA files that rely on a Protobuf message with a map field results in "return type is not identical to nor covariant with return type"

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc, nvcc

I am trying to compile a project that uses CUDA, gRPC, and Protobuf.
The project was originally built with gRPC 1.20 and Protobuf 3.7, but I am using the latest version of gRPC (tried 1.55, 1.56.x, master).
The protobuf file has a message structure that has a map<string, string> field.

Here is an MRE for both the proto file and main file:

---

foo.proto

```
syntax = "proto3";
package Foo;

message Bar {
    map<string,string> baz = 1;
}

message Result {}

service FooService {
    rpc FooFunc (Bar) returns (Result) {}
}
```

---

main.cu

```cpp
#include "cpp/foo.pb.h"

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

---

I compiled the `.proto` file using `/usr/local/bin/protoc --grpc_out=cpp --cpp_out=cpp --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc=/usr/local/bin/grpc_cpp_plugin foo.proto`.  `protoc` and the other executables have the full path to make sure the same installation of protobuf is being used.

I can compile `main.cu` as a regular C++ file with the following command
`nvcc -x cpp main.cu -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -lprotoc -lcuda -lprotobuf -lgrpc++ -lgrpc -std=c++17`

If I compile it as a CUDA C++ file with this command
`nvcc -x cu main.cu -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -lprotoc -lprotobuf -lgrpc++ -lgrpc -std=c++17`, I get the following errors:

```
/usr/local/include/google/protobuf/map_field.h(708): error: return type is not identical to nor covariant with return type "google::protobuf::internal::UntypedMapBase *" of overridden virtual function "google::protobuf::internal::MapFieldBaseForParse::MutableMap"

/usr/local/include/google/protobuf/map_field.h(626): error: return type is not identical to nor covariant with return type "google::protobuf::internal::UntypedMapBase *" of overridden virtual function "google::protobuf::internal::MapFieldBaseForParse::MutableMap"
          detected during instantiation of class "google::protobuf::internal::MapField<Derived, Key, T, kKeyFieldType_, kValueFieldType_> [with Derived=Foo::Bar_BazEntry_DoNotUse, Key=std::string, T=std::string, kKeyFieldType_=google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite::TYPE_STRING, kValueFieldType_=google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite::TYPE_STRING]" 
cpp/foo.pb.h(272): here

2 errors detected in the compilation of "main.cu".
```

I tried using multiple versions of gRPC (1.55, 1.56.x, and the master branch) and the latest version of Abesail (master branch). I also tried different installation paths for Protobuf/gRPC, such as `/usr/local`, `$HOME/.local`, and `$HOME/.grpc`, which results in the same error.

Running `nvcc main.cu --keep` only  generates `main.cpp4.ii`. It does not generate `main.cpp1.ii`, which might mean that the error is coming from the C++ preprocessor for CUDA code. How do I address this issue?

Note: I am using CMake to compile this project, but I am using the `nvcc ...` command here since that specific command is where CMake encounters the error.

**Update:** I was finally able to compile the project, but I used an older version of gRPC (v1.50 and v1.54 both work). There seems to be something different in the versions after gRPC 1.54 that causes an error on the CUDA-side of NVCC.